# How to setup a compute cluster in local network on top of linux

Tags: manjaro, cluster, python3

I have 3 machines in my local network running manjaro. I am running python scripts using dask, pandas, etc which max out the cpu on the first machine and I usually need to wait more than 30 min until the task finishes. Since I have 3 machines already setup in my local network for other purposes I would like to benefit from their cpus as well. I do not want to change the linux distro and want to continue to run other servers on those machines. I usually run python scripts which could be optimized for multiprocessing easily (just for loops on independent data)
Is there a way I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far too broad a topic to go into in great detail here, but as a quick outline, you will need:

- some sort of shared storage (e.g. [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)) so that all machines have access to the scripts AND the data.
- a job scheduler and resource/workdload manager such as [slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/)
- possibly some kind of message passing library (like `mpi4py`) if your python processes need to talk to each other (not needed if they are entirely independent processes).
- BTW, for simplicity in avoiding permissions issues, all users running jobs **must** have the same UID & GID on all systems.

Make one of the machines the head or controller node.  This one should probably also be the storage server.  It should probably be the machine on your LAN that a) is least used, and b) has the most storage (or drive bays to install more storage).   You should submit your batch jobs on this machine.

BTW, The controller node can also act as a compute node.

The other two machines should be "compute nodes", and clients to the storage server (e.g. if using NFS, they should mount the NFS directory exported by the NFS server).

---

You probably don't want to go this far, but on a dedicated cluster, you'd have one or more machines being storage nodes (nfs or [ceph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_(software)) or whatever), there would also be some centralised authentication server ([nis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) or [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) or something), and all users both the head node and the compute nodes would mount their home directories from the file server.

It is, however, worth looking into how "real" clusters are designed and built (or at least get an overview) because you can get some great ideas from them that you can scale down to your 3-node cluster.